# angular ui-select not rendering input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-select

Hey guys im mindf*cked,

i have an angular 1.4.7 project and want to use 'ui.select' but im getting always this errors:

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$compile/tpload?p0=bootstrap%2Fmatch-multiple.tpl.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found
Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$compile/tpload?p0=bootstrap%2Fchoices.tpl.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found
Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$compile/tpload?p0=bootstrap%2Fselect-multiple.tpl.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found
```

I have tested everything :(

Here they are talking about the Problem but there is no Solution:
[Github Issue #992](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/992)

My index.html js part (css is included in head):

```
<!-- BEGIN CORE ANGULARJS PLUGINS -->
    <script src="plugins/angularjs/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/angularjs/angular-sanitize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/angularjs/angular-touch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/angularjs/angular-translate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/angularjs/plugins/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/angularjs/angular-cookies.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/angularjs/plugins/angular-ui-router.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/angularjs/plugins/ocLazyLoad.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/angularjs/plugins/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/angularjs/plugins/ng-country-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/angularjs/plugins/ui-select/select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END CORE ANGULARJS PLUGINS -->
    <!-- BEGIN JS PLUGINS -->
    <script id="ng_load_scripts_after"></script>
    <!-- END JS PLUGINS -->
    <!-- BEGIN APP LEVEL ANGULARJS SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/filters.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/services/AlertService.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/services/ToastrService.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/services/RequestService.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END APP LEVEL ANGULARJS SCRIPTS -->
```

My directive call:

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="vm.legalbranches">
      <ui-select-match placeholder="Select legalbranch...">{{$item.label}}</ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices repeat="legalbranch in legalbranches | filter: {label: $select.search} track by legalbranch.id">
               <span ng-bind="legalbranch.label"></span>
                <!--{{legalbranch.label}}-->
      </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

vm.legalbranches and legalbranches are set in controller via resolve. Legalbranches is an array of objects.

I am using ui-select in version 0.14.8 and
angular-ui-bootstrap in version 0.14.0
and angular in 1.4.7

Where the hack is the Problem???

EDIT:
This is the result in the dom after loading the site:

```
<ui-select multiple="" ng-model="vm.legalbranches" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope"></ui-select>
```

Comment: I think from somewhere in your code you are doing `$templateCache.removeAll()` which removes up `ui-select` templates, which it then don't find while rendering.

Comment: i searched my whole project structure and did not found the "$templateCache.removeAll()"

Answer (score 0):

i am using oclazyload and i did the following to get the ui select running:

```
                    {
                        name: 'ui.select',
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before '#ng_load_plugins_before'
                        files: [
                            'plugins/angularjs/plugins/ui-select/select.min.css',
                            'plugins/angularjs/plugins/ui-select/select.js' //use the non minify because we have custom edits in it
                        ]
                    },
```

i used in the name field my app name but i had to use ui.select

thx for the help